# plot multiple values dataframe ​with date python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
          date      high      low  Sentiment
0   2018-02-01  10288.80  8812.28         -4
1   2018-02-02   9142.28  7796.49         -1
2   2018-02-03   9430.75  8251.63         -2
3   2018-02-04   9334.87  8031.22          7
4   2018-02-05   8364.84  6756.68         -4
5   2018-02-06   7850.70  6048.26        -12
6   2018-02-07   8509.11  7236.79        -11
7   2018-02-08   8558.77  7637.86        -17
8   2018-02-09   8736.98  7884.71          9
9   2018-02-10   9122.55  8295.47         -4
10  2018-02-11   8616.13  7931.10          4
11  2018-02-12   8985.92  8141.43          0
12  2018-02-13   8958.47  8455.41         -3
13  2018-02-14   9518.54  8599.92         -4
```

My final goal is to represent all the values ​​from the dataframe but I can't see the dates on the x-axis. I used this code:

```
df = Original_df [['date', 'high', 'low', 'Sentiment']].copy()
ax = df.plot(secondary_y='Sentiment')
ax.set_yscale('linear')
plt.show()
```

[image]

update: even in this way I don't see the dates. What am I doing wrong?

```
df = Original_df[['date', 'high', 'low', 'Sentiment']].copy()
    df = df.set_index('date')
    ax = df.plot(secondary_y='Sentiment')
    ax.set_yscale('linear')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you want your date column to be on the x axis you have to make it the index of your dataframe, try `df.set_index('date', inplace=True)` and then `df.plot`...

Comment: Have you though about putting `df.plot(label='date')`?

Comment: thanks for the help but the desired values ​​do not appear

Comment: @PabloPicciau sorry, I meant to say`df.plot(x='date, y='high')` but I guess you'll need 3 plots.

Comment: instead of numbers I only see the word "date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
ax = df.plot(secondary_y='Sentiment')
```

[image]